# awk : how to pass and use array value

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have `awk` script which will read SEARCH keywords from `input1.txt` and it will search if that SEARCH string 
is present in `input2.xml`

```
$ cat myAwk.awk
NR==FNR {
keywordArray[NR]=$0;
next;
}

/<record / { i=1 }
i { a[i++]=$0 }
/<\/record>/ {
    if (found) {
        for (i=1; i<=length(a); ++i) print a[i] >> result.txt
    }
    i=0;
    found=0
}
/<keyword>KEYWORD1<\/keyword>/ { found=1 }
/<keyword>KEYWORD2<\/keyword>/ { found=1 }
.....
```

This is where I need help. I need to pass KEYWORD value stored in keywordArray.

```
$ cat input1.txt
KEYWORD1
KEYWORD2
KEYWORD3
...

$ cat input2.xml
<record category="xyz">
<person ssn="" e-i="E">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>KEYWORD1</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>KEYWORD1 is present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</record>

<record category="abc">
<person ssn="" e-i="F">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>DONTSEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is not present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</record>

$ awk -f myAwk.awk input1.txt input2.xml
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is the whole record content from `<record>` to `</record>` should be written to `result.txt`. Only those records whose `<keyword>` tag value matches with `KEYWORDS`

Answer (score 0):

I'd either rewrite input1.txt to a bash file setting the array of keywords.
This way you can call the script using source and the array will be set in the calling script.

Otherwise you could loop through the input like this:

```
input=$(cat $0)
delimiter="\n" #I don't know that this works, otherwise you'll have to replace the newlines with something else
i=0
j=0
while [ ${#input} -gt 0 ]
do
    if [ ${input:$j:1} == delimiter ]
    then
        keywordArray[i]=${input:0:$((j-1))}
        input=${input:$((j+1))}
        j = 0
        ((++i))
    else
        ((++j))
    fi
done
```

Comment: If those are shell assignments, you can't have spaces around the `=` signs.  If they're `awk` assignments, `while` doesn't use `do` or `done`.  You also need to work on the condition in the `while` and `if` statement, whether it is shell or `awk` — but the work needed is different depending on whether it is shell or `awk`.  In general, I agree with your first paragraph: use `awk` or `sed` or something to convert the list of keywords into the required `awk` script and then run the result.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I haven't programmed in bash for the longest time.

Comment: Better, but there are no commands `++i` and `++j` on most machines.  You probably had `((++i))` and `((++j))` in mind in Bash.  POSIX would use `$((…))` and I reserve judgement on whether increments can be used then.  Also, `cat $0` might list the script into `input`, assuming Bash has provided a valid pathname for the script as `$0`.

Comment: @S.Klumpers `keywordArray[i]=${input:0:$((j-1))}` looks like assigning values to `keywordArray`. But, where is this `keywordArray` used while doing the search from the contents of the XML file?

Comment: I don't know, I thought you were having problems converting input1.txt to an array. To search input2.xml you could for example loop through the array and loop through inpu2.xml for each keyword.

Comment: Don't do this. Shell is for manipulating files and processes and for sequencing calls to tools. It is NOT for manipulating text and so any time you write a shell loop to do so you have the wrong approach. See, for example, the discussion at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{keywords[$0]++;next} /^<record/{p=1;data=""} p{data = data RS $0;} /^<\/record/{for(key in keywords){if(data ~ key){print data}}}' input1.txt input2.xml
```

More readable `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{keywords[$0]++;next}
     /^<record/{p=1;data=""} 
     p{data = data RS $0;} 
     /^<\/record/{for(key in keywords){if(data ~ key){print data}}}' input1.txt input2.xml
```

Comment: I have `KEYWORD1`, `KEYWORD2`, `KEYWORD3` (3 keywords). This matches with 2 `<record>..</record>` contents. So, the output is 3*2=6 record contents. Search logic seems wrong. Also, I didn't get `RS`. Seems it is not assigned any value.

Answer (score 0):

`I need to pass KEYWORD value stored in keywordArray.` - no, you don't, you just need to not use an array to store it in the first place. Just tweak the answer I gave you in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211943/1745001 to be something like:

```
$ awk  '
      NR==FNR{keys=keys sep $0; sep="|"; next}
      {ORS=RT} $0~"<keyword>("keys")</keyword>"
  ' input1.txt RS='</record>\n' input2.xml
```

The above is untested since you didn't accept the answer first time so I don't want to spend too much effort on modifying it this time. It should be close though and hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I had to accept the other answer as it was close to what I was expecting as answer. BTW it was me who had upvoted your answer to the one you had linked here.

Comment: No problem, I just don't want to put too much effort into an answer that isn't what you're looking for.