# awk : Not able to access the passed parameter

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am invoking `myAwk.awk` like below from shell script,

`awk -f myAwk.awk -v inputKeyword="SEARCH" file2.xml`

```
$bash: cat myAwk.awk
BEGIN{
print "This is from awk script:"  inputKeyword; //This prints SEARCH string. Fine.
}

/<record / { i=1 }
i { a[i++]=$0 }
/<\/record>/ {
    if (found) {
        for (i=1; i<=length(a); ++i) print a[i] >> resultFile.xml
    }
    i=0;
    found=0
}
/<keyword>inputKeyword<\/keyword>/ { found=1 }  //Looks like the value for inputKeyword is not available here.
//There are no errors though.
```

How can I make the value of `inputKeyword` to be available at my required place?

Comment: You can't use it with `/.../`, use `~` to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line,

```
/<keyword>inputKeyword<\/keyword>/ { found=1 }
```

to

```
$0 ~ "<keyword>"inputKeyword"</keyword>" { found=1 }
```

You do not required `//`, if matching pattern(`regex`) is in variable. `awk` won't interpolate what's between `//`. It will be considered just a string in there.

Comment: What value does `$0` hold ? Why do I require `$0`?

Comment: @user2488578, `$0` will have current line. It is a `awk`s build-in variable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page you should pass the options before `-f`:

> `SYNOPSIS`
>
> ```
>    `gawk [ POSIX or GNU style options ] -f program-file [ -- ] file ...`
>    `gawk [ POSIX or GNU style options ] [ -- ] program-text file ...`
> ```